# Calculating attributed string height

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set a tableViewCell height equal to the height of the `attributedString` inside the cell. However whatever I do it does not seem to have the correctSize. this is what I've tried so far

**cellHeight**

```
//Convert description to NSAttributedString and get height
//width is equal to screen width - right and left offset
//at the end add the bottom and height offset to the cell height
return detailPetViewModel!.description
                .lineSpacing(spacing: 4)
                .heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: Sizes.screenWidth - 40) + 10
```

**Customize descLabel in cell subclass**

```
//Customize descLabel
descLabel.font = FontFamily.Avenir.Regular.font(size: 16)
descLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: .SecondaryTextColor)

//Multiple lines
descLabel.numberOfLines = 0
descLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
descLabel.sizeToFit()
```

**linespacing extension**

```
extension String {
    func lineSpacing(spacing: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = spacing

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        return attributedString
    }
}
```

**height Extension**

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

        return boundingBox.height
    }

}
```

Comment: why don't you use the advantage of the dynamic cell-height instead?

Answer (score 35):

This is the extension I use. You shouldn't have to pass in any information about the font or line-height as the attributed string already knowns its values.

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    func height(containerWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let rect = self.boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: containerWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                     options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                     context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.size.height)
    }

    func width(containerHeight: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let rect = self.boundingRect(with: CGSize.init(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: containerHeight),
                                     options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                     context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.size.width)
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
let height = detailPetViewModel!.description.height(containerWidth: Sizes.screenWidth - 40 + 10)
```

Comment: You need to do a minor correction of the syntax in your (otherwise, quite correct) example: You used two periods (detailPetViewModel!.description..height), when it should be one (detailPetViewModel!.description.height)

Comment: Please note that "Font" attribute must be set in the attributed string, else calculation will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `(the instance of NSAttributedString).size.height`

e.g.

```swift
let a = NSAttributedString(string: "A string", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)])
let height = a.size().height
```

Comment: How about considering the given width?